# Magento2 dump the raw sql of a query before it is executed

Tags: magento2, sql

I have this resource

```
\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
```

and this connection object

```
$this->_connection = $resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
```

How do I dump the raw sql query that will be executed for example on the fallowing code:

```
$this->_connection->update('my_table',['my_field'=>$value],['field_equals'=>$field_value]);
```